# Problems extending pandas Panels dynamically, DataFrame by DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to construct a pandas panel dynamically, using the following - simplified - code:

```
import pandas as pd 
rows=range(0,3)
pl=pd.Panel()
for i in range(0,3):
    pl[i]=pd.DataFrame()
    for j in rows:
        pl[i].set_value(j,'test_value','test')
```

Which seems to work fine. But when I the try to index the individual dataframes by

```
for i in range(0,3):
    print pl[i]
```

I get the output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
  test_value
0     test20
1     test21
2     test22
```

Why are the first two frames empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two for loops to solve this problem:

```
import pandas as pd 

rows=range(0,3)
pl=pd.Panel()

#first for loop to create dataframe
for i in range(0,3):
    pl[i]=pd.DataFrame()

#Second for loop to assign values
for i in range(0,3):    
    for j in rows:
        pl[i].set_value(j,'test_value','test')
```

This time you won't get empty dataframes :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot construct all the dataframes before assigning the values. In my specific problem, I really have to do it in the order: Panel, DataFrame1, Row1,Row2, DataFrame2, Row1,Row2, etc.
Why doesn't my code work?